# Using splinter to access elements in popup window

Tags: python, popupwindow, splinter

On clicking a button on a webpage, a new window opens which on 'inspect element' looks like this:

```
<div id="editPhoneModal" class="modal hide" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="editPhoneLabel"
 aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>

    <h3 id="editPhoneLabel">Edit Phone Properties</h3>
  </div>

  <div class="modal-body">
  </div>
```

When i use find_by_xpath to find elements ()  seen after this window opens, it says 'element not found'

How can I use splinter to access the elements seen AFTER this window appears? Below is my code:

```
from splinter import Browser          
driver = Browser('firefox')
driver.visit('http://website.com')

driver.find_by_id('user').fill('myname')
driver.find_by_id('password').fill('123456')
driver.find_by_text('Sign in').first.click()

driver.find_by_xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/table/tbody/tr[6]/td[1]/i").first.click()#pop-up window appears

driver.find_by_xpath("//*[@class='select2-input']").fill('newphone')
```

I have seen solutions with selenium, but nothing with splinter.

Comment: Is the statement that is failing `driver.find_by_xpath("//*[@class='select2-input']").fill('newphone')`?